# How to efficiently copy one PipedOutputStream to another PipedOutputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, java-io, outputstream

I would like to copy one `PipedOutputStream` to another `PipedOutputStream` is it possible to do using the best practices and memory efficiently?

I have a method that writes the values to `PipedOutputStream output1` but after completing the whole process, I would like to copy these values into another `PipedOutputStream output2`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Following is the method that I have:

```
private InputStream converterMethod(final InputStream inputDocument) {
    try {

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

        final PipedOutputStream output1 = new PipedOutputStream();
        final CurrentHandler handler = new CurrentHandler(output1);

        final PipedOutputStream output2 = new PipedOutputStream();
        final InputStream finalInputStream = new PipedInputStream(output2);

        executorService.execute(
            () -> {
            try {
                new ConverterApplication().convert(inputDocument, handler);
                output1.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            });

        executorService.execute(() ->{
        try {
            //Planning to copy the output1 to output2 in the best way possible.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        });

        return finalInputStream;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyCustomException("Exception occurred during");
    }
}
```

I tried to keep only one `PipedOutputStream` something like this, in this case everything works fine, but when I make a call to this function from my Quarkus RestAPI then I am getting the error:

```
Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 620239 ms, time limit is 2000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
at java.base@17.0.3/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.base@17.0.3/java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:326)
at java.base@17.0.3/java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
at java.base@17.0.3/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:218)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.providers.serialisers.InputStreamMessageBodyHandler.writeTo(InputStreamMessageBodyHandler.java:39)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.providers.serialisers.ServerInputStreamMessageBodyHandler.writeResponse(ServerInputStreamMessageBodyHandler.java:46)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.providers.serialisers.ServerInputStreamMessageBodyHandler.writeResponse(ServerInputStreamMessageBodyHandler.java:16)
```

```
private InputStream converterMethod(final InputStream inputDocument) {
    try {

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

        final PipedOutputStream output1 = new PipedOutputStream();
        final CurrentHandler handler = new CurrentHandler(output1);

        final InputStream finalInputStream = new PipedInputStream(output1);

        executorService.execute(
            () -> {
            try {
                new ConverterApplication().convert(inputDocument, handler);
                output1.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return finalInputStream;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyCustomException("Exception occurred during");
    }
}
```

Basically al I want to achieve is how to obtain the final information as InputStream from my `ConverterApplication()`

Comment: What about `finalInputStream.transferTo(output2)`?

Comment: @dan1st Thanks a lot for response. I tried this but this is not working for some reason.